# Use CLOUD DNS to manage custom DNS for my customers

Tags: domain-name-system, google-cloud-platform, nameserver, dns-zone, google-cloud-dns

I need to manage custom domain for my customer on my app engine.
I've seen "Cloud DNS", with this i can give NS to my customers, they update their NS to their DNS and game is done.
So my customers will connect they **customer.com** to my **customer.appengine.com**. 
Url, when an use go to customer.com, will remain customer.com.

I can't find documentation abount Cloud DNS used with app engine, it's this possibile?

Actually i've tried setup the cloud DNS, this is what i have

```
    customer.com. SOA   21600   ns-cloud-f1.googledomains.com. cloud-dns-hostmaster.google.com. 1 21600 3600  259200 300
    customer.com.   NS  21600   ns-cloud-f1.googledomains.com.
                                ns-cloud-z2.googledomains.com.
                                ns-cloud-x3.googledomains.com.
                                ns-cloud-a4.googledomains.com.
    www.customer.com.   CNAME   300   customer.appengine.com.
```

My customer has setted correct registrar confguration (added DNS gave me from google) to his DNS.

I'm running nslookup on my domain, and got this:

```
nslookup www.customer.com                                                      
Server:         192.168.1.1                                                                                                          
Address:        192.168.1.1#53                                                                                                       
Non-authoritative answer:                                                                                                            
www.customer.com             canonical name = customer.appengine.com.                                                                          
customer.appengine.com       canonical name = ghs.googlehosted.com.                                                                       Name:   ghs.googlehosted.com                                                                                                         Address: xxx.xxx.xx.xxx                                                                                                              Name:   ghs.googlehosted.com                                                                                                         Address: xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::xxxx
```

This seems correct to me, but always get 404 google page!

Comment: Have you tried to follow documentation [Mapping Custom Domains]
(https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mapping-custom-domains)?

Comment: Yes, now i've domain setted. But there is a problem: While configuring domain i have to set 4 A records and 4 AAAA records with empty alias. I actually can set only one (because can't set empty A and AAAA alias for records and can't have same A and AAAA record on the same Alias). I suppose that if i set only ONE A and AAAA record...i will get some problem.

Answer (score 0):

When setting the 4 A and AAAA records, the alias are not empty they [should have](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mapping-custom-domains?hl=is#dns_update) @

I have my domain with godaddy and this worked fine for me. 
If you have your domain with Google Domain here is the [documentation](https://support.google.com/domains/answer/6009957?hl=en) for it, although the same applies, its needed to set the A and AAAA records along with the CNAME that App engine custom domain settings screen displays

Answer (score 0):

**Your [Cloud DNS](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/overview) records looks OK**, but [make sure](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mapping-custom-domains#dns_update) that the `A` and `AAAA` records for the `customer.com` domain contain only `@` character. Better to double check that.

Also - I see that `CNAME` record points to `customer.appengine.com` which is also correct.

**I believe we can rule out Cloud DNS setup at this point.**

Additionally - since you can `nslookup` your domain and you get a correct IP (the one that `customer.appengine.com` points to) and other records then it should work. Even your `CNAME` record has propagated properly.

**To rule out any DNS configuration entirely** browse to `customer.appengine.com` and se if you can access the app. If you can double check DNS setting (despite they "look" ok). If you cannot however check the app itself and the [App Engine firewall rules](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/creating-firewalls#creating_firewall_rules) which are a separate thing from firewall controlling access to Compute Engine VM's.